# How do I access something in a JSON file when there are quotes around the key?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object that I fetched from an API.

```
{
  "response": "success",
  "id": "641",
  "name": "Superboy",
  "powerstats": {
    "intelligence": "75",
    "strength": "95",
    "speed": "83",
    "durability": "90",
    "power": "95",
    "combat": "60"
  },
  "biography": {
    "full-name": "Kon-El / Conner Kent",
    "alter-egos": "No alter egos found.",
   .....
```

I can't use a `-` because JS thinks it's an operator.

Comment: Use bracket notation `myObj.biography['full-name']`

Answer (score 0):

> **Property accessors** provide access to an object's properties by using the dot notation or the bracket notation. [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

When accessing an object property in JavaScript you can use both:

```
Object.response // dot notation
```

Or

```
Object['response'] // bracket notation
```

> In the object[property_name] syntax, the property_name is just a string or Symbol. So, it can be any string, including '1foo', '!bar!', or even ' ' (a space). [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

In your case, since you have a special character as the property, you would call your `biography` properties using the bracket notation.

```
console.log(Object.biography['full-name']); // Kon-El / Conner Kent
console.log(Object['biography']['alter-ego']); //  No alter egos found.
```

For more details on how objects work in JavaScript you can read up [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)